# How does addView() of TableRow work?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried

```
 private void addSnapPictureRow(TableLayout table, Bitmap bitmap) {
        /*
         * 1st row = TextView (Check In)
         */
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);  
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        // add text
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Snap Picture");
        TableRow.LayoutParams textLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textLayoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
        row.addView(text, textLayoutParams);

        // add picture
        ImageView picture = new ImageView(this);
        picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.adium);
        row.addView(picture);

        /*
         * 2nd row = View (separator)
         */
        TableRow separator = new TableRow(this);
        View line = new View(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams separatorLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        separatorLayoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
        line.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        separator.addView(line, separatorLayoutParams);

        // add row to table
        table.addView(row);
        // add a separator
        table.addView(separator);
    }
```

But the picture never showed. If I change the gravity to `CENTER_HORIZONTAL`, then it shows only a small part of the picture.

[image]

When create table with xml, I thought it automatically aligned horizontally. I can't understand how TableRow layout works. Could anyone shed me some lights on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an extra `LinearLayout` for each row solved my problem ;). The algignment of the previous row cause the picture go out of screen.

```
private void addSnapPictureRow(TableLayout table, Bitmap bitmap) {
        /*
         * 1st row = TextView (Check In)
         */
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);  
        LinearLayout outerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // add text
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Snap Picture");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textLayoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);

        // add picture
        ImageView picture = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams pictureLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.adium);
        pictureLayoutParams.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);

        outerLayout.addView(text, textLayoutParams);
        outerLayout.addView(picture, pictureLayoutParams);
        row.addView(outerLayout);

        /*
         * 2nd row = View (separator)
         */
        TableRow separator = new TableRow(this);
        View line = new View(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams separatorLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(400, 1);
        separatorLayoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
        line.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        separator.addView(line, separatorLayoutParams);

        // add row to table
        table.addView(row);
        // add a separator
        table.addView(separator);
    }
```